# How to pass values from HTML page to ASPX?

Tags: html, asp.net

I have two files html and .aspx, both the files have two text boxes. When user files values in text box in html page and click submit, values should be filled in .aspx page. I tried many ways but could not get the exact thing what I needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can just use simple HTML form GET method like this:

//your html file e.g. HtmlPage1.html

> ```
> <!DOCTYPE html>
> <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> <head>
> <title></title> </head> <body>
> <form action="WebForm1.aspx" method="get">
>     Choose your favorite subject:
>     <button name="subject" type="submit">send my value</button>
>     <input id="name" name="name"  type="text" />
> </form> </body> </html>
> ```

//your aspx file e.g. WebForm1.aspx

> ```
> <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="AssessorsLounge.WebForm1" %>
>
> <!DOCTYPE html>
>
> <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> <head runat="server">
> <title></title> </head> <body>
> <form id="form1" runat="server">
> <div>
> <%: Request.QueryString["name"].ToString() %>
> </div>
> </form> </body> </html>
> ```

you could learn more about html and asp.net on [www.w3schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_value.asp)